# How to get related model's field by django filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

So here is the scenario. I get user_id and do a filter named generated. I want to show all the values of class C by order of check.

Here is my models.py

```
class A(models.Model):
    tob = models.ForeignKey(B)

    def something(self, user):
        return A.objects.filter(to_b=user)

class B(models.Model):
    bid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class C(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tobid = models.ForeignKey(B)
    check = models.datetimeField()
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def generated(request,user_id):

    f= A()
    p = f.something(user_id)
```

I can perform a for loop that will get all values of class C.

My views to fetch value from C

```
    for des in p:
        des_list = des.tob.bid
        des_list_final = C.objects.filter(tobid = des_list)
```

But the problem in here that everytime it takes one id from B and perform the filtering to C. But this will not give me the value of C order by check. Any idea how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to show all the values of class C by order of check.

`C.objects.filter(tobid__id__in=[des.tob.bid.pk for des in p]).order_by('-check')`

If you want to set the order permanently, use [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.ordering):

```
class C(models.Model):

   class Meta:
     ordering = ['-check']
```

Comment: May be I could not clear my question ..I know to use order_by..But problem lied on my for loop..It fetches all the value of C ( order by check) for single b_id every time..(So if first b_id is 1 and its one check  on 11 december and another on 10 october, it will come first orderly.Then passed 2nd bid and its check on 11 november,it will come at no 3 )..But I did not want this..I want to show the check according to date orderly...I am not sure whether I could clear myself.